# Microsoft Graph Get All Users Exception Unsupported Query

Tags: c#, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I can submit this query to Microsoft Graph Explorer but in C# I get the an error message: "Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: "Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
Message: Unsupported Query."

```
var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Filter("endswith(mail,'@mydomain.com')")
    .OrderBy("userPrincipalName")
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should send a header `ConsistencyLevel=eventual` and also $count query parameter to make it work.

To add $count query parameter you can use queryOptions.

```cs
List<QueryOption> queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>
{                                                  
    new QueryOption("$count", true) 
}; 

var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request(queryOptions)
    .Filter("endswith(mail,'@mydomain.com')")
    .OrderBy("userPrincipalName")
    .GetAsync();
```

The API call what look something like this

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=endswith(mail, '@domain.live')&$orderBy=userPrincipalName
```

You can always test these calls in Graph Explorer.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10324#issuecomment-801222042

Comment: QueryOption accepts two String parameters. Thus it shall be:
"...new QueryOption("$count", "true")..."
see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.graph.queryoption?view=graph-core-dotnet